# How to increase Kotlin coroutines Dispatchers.IO size on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Coroutines `Dispatchers.IO` context is limited to 64 threads. That's not enough to reliably interface with blocking code in highly-concurrent system.

[Documentation states](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) that:

> Additional threads in this pool are created and are shutdown on
>   demand. The number of threads used by this dispatcher is limited by
>   the value of “kotlinx.coroutines.io.parallelism”
>   (IO_PARALLELISM_PROPERTY_NAME) system property. It defaults to the
>   limit of 64 threads or the number of cores (whichever is larger).

I want to change `kotlinx.coroutines.io.parallelism` system property to something else. However, if I just do this:

```
adb shell "setprop kotlinx.coroutines.io.parallelism 1000"
```

then I get the following result:

```
setprop: failed to set property 'kotlinx.coroutines.io.parallelism' to '1000'
```

Furthermore, if I want to ship my app, then I'll need to change this property on users' devices as well, right? Otherwise the app won't work. However, even assuming that it's possible, as far as I understand, all apps that change this property will override the setting for one another. This doesn't sound like a reliable mode of operation.

So, I have three questions in this context:

1. Is the property implied in documentation is indeed the "system property" that I tried to change?
2. How to change this property on non-rooted device for all users of my app?
3. Is there better alternative?

P.S. I know that if I'd only use coroutines, without blocking code, this wouldn't be a problem (probably). But let's just assume that I need to use blocking calls (e.g. legacy Java code).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`IO_PARALLELISM_PROPERTY_NAME` does not refer to an *Android* system property, but to a **Java system property**. Just add this code early in your app, e.g. first in your `Application.onCreate()`, to change it to `1000`:

```
import static kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchersKt.IO_PARALLELISM_PROPERTY_NAME;

System.setProperty(IO_PARALLELISM_PROPERTY_NAME, Integer.toString(1000));
```

This does *not* have to be done on a per-device basis with root or anything like that. It will work everywhere, since it is regular app code using regular app APIs.

As long as you do this before you use `Dispatchers.IO` for the first time, your property change will be applied.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Tested and it works. Thanks a lot.
Do you think it will also change the size of Dispatchers.IO in libs that I might import?

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` is an app-wide singleton. If a dependency uses coroutines, it will still use the same coroutine library as your own code, and therefore the same thread pool.

Answer (score 13):

You can create your own dispatcher with any number of threads, like so

```
val dispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(128).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Comment: Very handy, thanks. However, if I'm not mistaken, it addresses only part of the problem. What if one of the libs I import uses Dispatchers.IO internally?

Comment: Yes, only addresses the issue of a highly multithreaded app with blocking code, I'm not certain you can alter how libs would use dispatchers.

Answer (score 3):

With kotlinx-coroutines-1.6.0 you can limit the threads that are used for Dispatchers by using "limitedParallelism" method.

Example:

```
// 100 threads for MySQL connection
val myMysqlDbDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(100)
// 60 threads for MongoDB connection
val myMongoDbDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(60)
```

Release note: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#dispatcher-views-api

Answer (score 0):

◘ **For whole the System use this way**

```
System.setProperty(IO_PARALLELISM_PROPERTY_NAME, Integer.toString(256));
```

◘ **create a new Dispatcher**

```
val customIODispatcher = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(256)
launch(customIODispatcher) {
      //...
}
```

`customIODispatcher` is a new Dispatcher and limitedParallelism is 256